# Понимание массивов классового типа

Tags: java, массивы, классы, инициализация

[image: Обьесните, пожалуйста, для чего нужна 16-ая строка...Ведь если уже был инициализирован массив с его тримя элементами...]

Обьесните, пожалуйста, для чего нужна 16-ая строка...Ведь если уже был инициализирован массив с его тремя элементами, почему нужно делать это снова?...

Comment: потому что память выделена только под сам массив, а не под элементы. Но это в случае классов, в случае структур вроде не надо :) Хотя тут похоже Java и структур нет :-) так что всегда надо :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформляйте код текстом, а не скриншотом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что, когда ты делаешь так

```
Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[3]
```

ты создаешь только массив своих объектов. Если посмотреть, что лежит в этом массиве, то ты увидишь, что там лежат 3 объекта, которые ссылаются на `null`.

Для того, чтобы заполнить массив, как раз и вызывается 16 строчка из твоего кода.

12 строка инициализирует массив, 16 строка инициализирует элементы массива.

Comment: "12 строка инициализирует массив, 16 строка инициализирует элементы массива."    Разве я не инициализирую элементы на 18 ой строке?  (Должен был быть Х вместо 0). Даже если элементы null почему нельза сразу заполнить элементы массива по индексу (как на 18 ой строке)?

Comment: на 18 строке ты проставляешь какие-то поля у данного объекта, а не создаешь его. Если ты не создашь объект и будешь проставлять значения, то у тебя будет NullPointerException

Comment: Ok,понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Согласно [Java-спецификации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

... Каждый элемент массива инициализируется стандартным значением (§15.9, §15.10):

> Для всех ссылочных типов (§4.3) стандартным значением является `null`.

Таким образом в первой строке выделяется память под массив из 3 элементов, каждый из которых имеет значение `null`.

P.S.: судя по вашему коду, вы выделяете память под 3 элемента, но в цикле переменная x изменяется от 0 до 3 включительно, т.е. инициализируете 4 элемента. Должно появляться исключение [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).